# how to synchronize text to the video timecode?

Tags: sync

I am wondering how to add text which is updated along the time code of the video.

Concretely, I have a gopro footage and a file of some performances values (speed, heart rate, cadence,...) that I want to overlay with correct values at the right moment.

I have a csv file with time in first col, and other parameters in following cols.

I'm quite new in video production, so I not particularly familiar to any software (so there's no need on a particular platform solution)

**EDIT - solution :** I found a nice solution perfectly answering my question : http://www.dashware.net . I'll try it later but it seems the right solution !

Comment: I can supply a detailed answer when I have more time but your best bet is to use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org), specifically its [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) filter. Basic idea is to create a script that parses your CSV file and composes one very looong ffmpeg command containing drawtext filters - one for each line in your CSV.

Comment: Davinci Resolve lite is free, and you can "burn in" timecode.

Comment: @JasonConrad  , what do you mean by "burn it" ? do you have any reference about resolving my issue with this software ?

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya ! This sounds nice, I'm exited to hear more !

Comment: "burn in" means write the timecode visually to the video file.  You can also write other information using the tools in Resolve.  Page 846 of the user manual.  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwivyP-Py6nJAhVMRCYKHbd6ACEQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocuments.blackmagicdesign.com%2FDaVinciResolve%2FDaVinci_Resolve_12_Manual_2015-07-27.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFPZAq2nl_BBOgXfw9rCUe4dN7Cnw&sig2=EBQ8R-nY3NbNs9nl2gWfvw

Comment: Dashware will be much more convenient. Add it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Jason, the OP wants to burn idiosyncratic dynamic data recorded as per timecode, and not the timecode or any of the Data Burn elements mentioned in the Resolve manual. Also don't see an option for Resolve to use a text file to source the changing data. If it is possible, can you write up an answer?

Comment: Tkanks @Mulvya I just founded this soft too ! I'll just need to find or create nice gauges, but that's another question ;)

Comment: @Mulvya, nmatton  I find the question confusing.  Perhaps one of you, who seem to understand it, could re-word it more clearly.

Comment: You need to drive the animation with the CSV data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice solution perfectly answering my question : http://www.dashware.net . I'll try it later but it seems the right solution !